# JADE using each on two arrays

Tags: pug

I can't seem to figure this out :/

```
    each pet in pets && user in users
        if user.email == pet.email
            li #{pet.name}
```

returns blank, while:

```
    each pet in pets 
    each user in users
     if user.email == pet.email
        li #{pet.name}
```

returns undefined for email

Comment: What's in your arrays?

Comment: ...strings :) total noob here, can you tell me what you mean?

Comment: Can you confirm that each array holds objects which have an email property? email returning undefined implies that there's no email property defined in either your users or your pets.

Comment: some have the email field empty, is that the problem?

Comment: As long as they have the field defined, it's not a problem for it to be empty. But they need to have the field defined at least. Does that make sense? This would be much easier to debug if you provided sample data which reproduces the issue.

Comment: it worked! i added the email field after some mongo pushes, some documents did not have that field! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're getting an error that says "email is undefined", that means that some object on which you're trying to access the `email` property does not actually have that property. If you make sure that all the objects in the array on which you're using `each` have all of the properties you're trying to access, you shouldn't get any undefined errors, even if those fields are empty. Typically a for-each type of loop is only used when you know that the objects you're iterating over have the same properties and methods, so they can be treated in the same way.